# Set Ajax Relative URL Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've got a MVC Application divided into areas and when I try to make a AJAX call from the Engineer area,  the relative URL get transformed into a URL that does not match my intent;

Here is the example:

This is URL on the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/JobData/GetSitesByClientId',
    data: {
        'clientId': selectedClient
    }
})
```

This is the URL generated:

```
http://localhost:53433/Engineer/Jobs/api/JobData/GetSitesByClientId?clientId=09659dc4-faa7-4edb-af27-ecb7416a82fb
```

And this is the URL I wanted to generate:

```
http://localhost:53433/api/JobData/GetSitesByClientId?clientId=09659dc4-faa7-4edb-af27-ecb7416a82fb
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Add a leading slash to the URL, so that you have `url: '/api/JobData/GetSitesByClientId',`.

Comment: Putting an `/` first should start from the host.

Comment: use `@Url.content("~/api/JobData/GetSitesByClientId")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can put a leading slash `/` at start of the URL. However, I do not recommend this method because if your application gets deployed on a subdirectory (eg:`www.host.com/myapp/`) , then the path would be wrong

What I do in such case is to define a global rootPath variable in the javascript context of my view

**Layout**

```
  <script>
    var rootPath = '@Url.Content("~")';
  </script>
```

Then in Javascript files I append the rootPath to any path i want to use

```
$.ajax({
    url: rootPath + 'mycontroller/mymethod',
    method: 'GET',
    success:function(){
      alert("success");
    }  

});
```